# System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes Access to the path denied

Tags: asp.net, pdf, readfile

Am running the project on the visual studio 2015, When I tried to read the PDF its giving me the following error;

> Access to the path 'E:\FILE\FILEUPLOAD\InnerFile\File' is denied.

**Function Defination**

```
    var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition { FileName = "PDF.pdf", Inline = true };

               string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping("PDF.pdf");
     Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString()); 
    var innerPath = "InnerFile/File" ;

                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(PDFUploadRootPath + innerPath + "/PDF.pdf");

byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(PDFUploadRootPath + innerPath);

            return File(bytes, contentType);
```

**NOTE:**

> - Given Full permission to user
> - Physically File Exists

I dont understand what to do now please help!

[image]

Comment: Do not use string concatenation when dealing with paths like this ```new FileInfo(PDFUploadRootPath + innerPath + "/PDF.pdf");```, use ```Path.Combine```. I see that you have forward slash ```/``` not backslash - assuming you're running on Windows, it's improper path separator.

Comment: Yes m running it on Windows ... File is found when check 'fi.Exists' . so its not a problem with the path its giving the error while reading @MarcinZablocki

Comment: If your intent is to read file from path ```PDFUploadRootPath + innerPath + "/PDF.pdf"```, then you're not doing this in the next line: ```System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(PDFUploadRootPath + innerPath)```.

Comment: Plus - maybe you have Deny access in your permission (Deny access rules are overriding Allow permission rules in NTFS).

Comment: Can you please tell me what should I do to fix this error ?

Comment: Check permissions table of this file and see if there is any deny rule there

Comment: Please post full stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `FileInfo` instance indeed references 'E:\FILE\FILEUPLOAD\InnerFile\File\PDF.pdf':

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(PDFUploadRootPath + innerPath + "/PDF.pdf");
```

but when trying to read the file contents you forgot the file name and only use the path 'E:\FILE\FILEUPLOAD\InnerFile\File':

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(PDFUploadRootPath + innerPath);
```

Thus, also add the file name for reading all file bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(PDFUploadRootPath + innerPath + "/PDF.pdf");
```

Furthermore, as others have mentioned in comments, you should really use `Path.Combine` to glue path parts together, not simple string concatenation...

Comment: AHHHHHHH, Thanx mate that was a silliest mistake :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using FileStream instead of byte array for reading the pdf file.

```
FileStream templateFileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
            return templateFileStream;
```

Also check (through code) if user has write permission to directory or path:

```
public static bool HasUserWritePermission(String path, String NtAccountName)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        DirectorySecurity acl = di.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All);
        AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = acl.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
        Boolean hasPermission = false;
        //Go through the rules returned from the DirectorySecurity
        foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in rules)
        {
            //If we find one that matches the identity we are looking for
            if (rule.IdentityReference.Value.Equals(NtAccountName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                //Cast to a FileSystemAccessRule to check for access rights
                if ((((FileSystemAccessRule)rule).FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.WriteData) > 0)
                {
                    hasPermission = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    hasPermission = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return hasPermission;
    }
```

Comment: But what do I need write permissions for if I only want to read the file?